# navigation.getChildNavigation is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Getting error after i update react-navigation package with > 2.2.5 (android/ios)

```
RN : 0.55.4
react : 16.3.1
react-navigation : 2.3.0
redux: 3.7.2
react-navigation-redux-helpers : 1.1.2
```

everything is working fine before updating react-navigation version

similar issue on git hub but still not resolved 
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4481

my navigation structure

```
StackNavigation
              |
            home 
              |
            login
              |
              .
              .
```

I have only one navigation no nesting

[image]

Comment: please give us some of your source code. navigation structure for example

Comment: okay i update in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two minutes ago i had the same problem. Just downgrade react-navigation version to 2.2.0, this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to resolve

1. Upgrading react-navigation-redux-helpers in the package.json to version 2.0.8.
2. Do not pass nav navigation prop down to your appNavigator, as in React-Navigation@latest persist its on state.

So instead of doing this

`<Provider>
    <AppNavigation navigation={navigation}/>
<Provider>`

do this

`<Provider>
<AppNavigation/>
<Provider>`

Comment: Where does AppNavigation come from and how can i pass dispatch,listener vs?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading react-navigation-redux-helpers in the package.json to version 2.0.8 solved this issue for me.